# Animate UICollectionViewCell Reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview

I have looked all over, without any luck. But I'll keep it short and sweet. I feel like I should be looking at `UICollectionViewLayout`, but am not entirely sure.

**I want to achieve:**
Custom animation for a UICollectionViewCell when the data is reloaded. E.g. Cell contents spirals in (as an example).

**How can I achieve this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Activity Indicator View. Your code will be like:

```
[yourAIV startAnimating];
[yourCollectionView reloadData];
[yourAIV stopAnimating];
```

Comment: I'm sorry you have completely misunderstood. I mean that I want each cell to have a custom animation. So for example, it might an image, that image might spin into view. I have no need for an activity indicator. Make a bit more sense?

Comment: I am also looking to achieve something like this.  Will try this out and post my finding.